# Why is RShiny shinyalert (callback) not rendering?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the example from Dean's `shinyalert` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert
actionButton("btn", "Greet")
     ),

server = function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$btn, {
  shinyalert(
    "Enter your name", type = "input",
    callbackR = function(x) { message("Hello ", x) },
    callbackJS = "function(x) { alert('Hello ' + x); }"
  )
})
 }
 )
```

[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

For some reason, the example shown on the github does not work on mine. And when I remove the callbackJS. Nothing happens. I input the name and click 'Ok' but the chain modal does not work.

[image: chainmodal]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use:

```
    callbackR = function(value) { shinyalert(paste("Welcome", value))}
```

It might also been what is shown in the docu: https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert#chaining.

Your code `message("Hello ", x)`, actually works as designed since it prints the message to the console.

Full code would read:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert
    actionButton("btn", "Greet")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      shinyalert(
        "Enter your name", type = "input",
        callbackR = function(value) { shinyalert(paste("Welcome", value))},
        callbackJS = "function(x) { alert('Hello ' + x); }"
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Right, it works as to print in the console (as does the .js) but it does not chain to another  modal. Sorry, perhaps I was not clear enough. I am trying to duplicate the GIF (chain modals) where one would input text(e.g. 'name') and another modal would render. The callbackR is not alerting via modal. Very odd..

Comment: If i run the "full code" at the bottom of my answer then i have to enter a name. Then the Javascript alert appears and next a second modal appears with "Welcome NAME". That should match the desired behaviour right?

Comment: Yep it should...i do not know why it will not T.T. I get the same output that you see in the images above.

Comment: Well, I think I discovered the problem. The chain ability, as seen in the GIF, is not in the CRAN version. I ended-up uninstalling `shinyalert` and then grabbing the GitHub repo: `devtools::install_github("daattali/shinyalert")`. Now it works.